# Jquery function does not work when click is simulated with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

I am using Opencart 2.3.0.2 and I am trying to change the html of the order edit page to be in one page layout (By default is with bootstrap tabs).
It looks like it's loading the information for the next tab when you click the button on the previous page to continue.
And when I change it to one page it does not load the information on 
document.ready but on click of the button.
I've got the following code:

```
$('#button-refresh').on('click', function() {
  console.log('you've clicked button-refresh');
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $catalog; ?>index.php?route=api/cart/products&token=' + token + '&store_id=' + $('select[name=\'store_id\'] option:selected').val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(json) {
            $('.alert-danger, .text-danger').remove();

            // Check for errors
            if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['warning']) {
                    $('#content > .container-fluid').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error']['warning'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
                }

                if (json['error']['stock']) {
                    $('#content > .container-fluid').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error']['stock'] + '</div>');
                }

                if (json['error']['minimum']) {
                    for (i in json['error']['minimum']) {
                        $('#content > .container-fluid').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error']['minimum'][i] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
                    }
                }
            }

            var shipping = false;

            html = '';
      console.log(json['products'].length);
            if (json['products'].length) {
                for (i = 0; i < json['products'].length; i++) {
                    product = json['products'][i];

                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-left">' + product['name'] + ' ' + (!product['stock'] ? '<span class="text-danger">***</span>' : '') + '<br />';
                    html += '  <input type="hidden" name="product[' + i + '][product_id]" value="' + product['product_id'] + '" />';

                    if (product['option']) {
                        for (j = 0; j < product['option'].length; j++) {
                            option = product['option'][j];

                            html += '  - <small>' + option['name'] + ': ' + option['value'] + '</small><br />';

                            if (option['type'] == 'select' || option['type'] == 'radio' || option['type'] == 'image') {
                                html += '<input type="hidden" name="product[' + i + '][option][' + option['product_option_id'] + ']" value="' + option['product_option_value_id'] + '" />';
                            }

                            if (option['type'] == 'checkbox') {
                                html += '<input type="hidden" name="product[' + i + '][option][' + option['product_option_id'] + '][]" value="' + option['product_option_value_id'] + '" />';
                            }

                            if (option['type'] == 'text' || option['type'] == 'textarea' || option['type'] == 'file' || option['type'] == 'date' || option['type'] == 'datetime' || option['type'] == 'time') {
                                html += '<input type="hidden" name="product[' + i + '][option][' + option['product_option_id'] + ']" value="' + option['value'] + '" />';
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    html += '</td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-left">' + product['model'] + '</td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-right"><div class="input-group btn-block" style="max-width: 200px;"><input type="text" name="product[' + i + '][quantity]" value="' + product['quantity'] + '" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_refresh; ?>" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></span></div></td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-right">' + product['price'] + '</td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-right">' + product['total'] + '</td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-center" style="width: 3px;"><button type="button" value="' + product['cart_id'] + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
                    html += '</tr>';

                    if (product['shipping'] != 0) {
                        shipping = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!shipping) {
                $('select[name=\'shipping_method\'] option').removeAttr('selected');
                $('select[name=\'shipping_method\']').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#button-shipping-method').prop('disabled', true);
            } else {
                $('select[name=\'shipping_method\']').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#button-shipping-method').prop('disabled', false);
            }

            if (json['vouchers'].length) {
                for (i in json['vouchers']) {
                    voucher = json['vouchers'][i];

                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-left">' + voucher['description'];
                    html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][code]" value="' + voucher['code'] + '" />';
                    html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][description]" value="' + voucher['description'] + '" />';
                    html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][from_name]" value="' + voucher['from_name'] + '" />';
                    html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][from_email]" value="' + voucher['from_email'] + '" />';
                    html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][to_name]" value="' + voucher['to_name'] + '" />';
                    html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][to_email]" value="' + voucher['to_email'] + '" />';
                    html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][voucher_theme_id]" value="' + voucher['voucher_theme_id'] + '" />';
                    html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][message]" value="' + voucher['message'] + '" />';
                    html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][amount]" value="' + voucher['amount'] + '" />';
                    html += '  </td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-left"></td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-right">1</td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-right">' + voucher['price'] + '</td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-right">' + voucher['price'] + '</td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-center" style="width: 3px;"><button type="button" value="' + voucher['code'] + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
                    html += '</tr>';
                }
            }

            if (!json['products'].length && !json['vouchers'].length) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '  <td colspan="6" class="text-center"><?php echo $text_no_results; ?></td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            }

            $('#cart').html(html);

            // Totals
            html = '';

            if (json['products'].length) {
                for (i = 0; i < json['products'].length; i++) {
                    product = json['products'][i];

                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-left">' + product['name'] + ' ' + (!product['stock'] ? '<span class="text-danger">***</span>' : '') + '<br />';

                    if (product['option']) {
                        for (j = 0; j < product['option'].length; j++) {
                            option = product['option'][j];

                            html += '  - <small>' + option['name'] + ': ' + option['value'] + '</small><br />';
                        }
                    }

                    html += '  </td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-left">' + product['model'] + '</td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-right">' + product['quantity'] + '</td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-right">' + product['price'] + '</td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-right">' + product['total'] + '</td>';
                    html += '</tr>';
                }
            }

            if (json['vouchers'].length) {
                for (i in json['vouchers']) {
                    voucher = json['vouchers'][i];

                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-left">' + voucher['description'] + '</td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-left"></td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-right">1</td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-right">' + voucher['amount'] + '</td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-right">' + voucher['amount'] + '</td>';
                    html += '</tr>';
                }
            }

            if (json['totals'].length) {
                for (i in json['totals']) {
                    total = json['totals'][i];

                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-right" colspan="4">' + total['title'] + ':</td>';
                    html += '  <td class="text-right">' + total['text'] + '</td>';
                    html += '</tr>';
                }
            }

            if (!json['totals'].length && !json['products'].length && !json['vouchers'].length) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '  <td colspan="5" class="text-center"><?php echo $text_no_results; ?></td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            }

            $('#total').html(html);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

and I tried hacking it by simulating a click when the document load like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button-refresh').trigger('click');
});
```

the strange thing is that it works fine when I click the button in the browser, but it gives me error when I try to simulate the click with jquery. The errors is when I am trying to console.log the json['products']. It says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at Object.success (index.php?route=sale/order/edit&order_id=18&token=m0x3pTbrP0KbaBKSIQR4Jw4XndGGbrAS:1002)
>       at j (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
>       at x (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4)

**EDIT:**
one more strange things is that the button does not have id="button-refresh" but it detects it somehow.
the button:

```
<button type="button" id="button-customer" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> <?php echo $button_continue; ?></button>
```

and when I tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button-customer').trigger('click');
});
```

nothing happens.

Comment: convert `id` of button to `class` of button and direct use `$(document).on('click','.button-refresh',function(){......your code....});` this will work for already present button as well as dynamically added button too. If button is single on the page then you can use `id` too

Comment: You could/should refactor your code so that the button click simply calls a function, then you can call that function as required - rather than "hack" a button event.

Comment: @freedomn-m I edit my question and added the button code :)

Comment: @freedomn-m the alert says 1

Comment: Ok - missed this most relevant part of the question: "*it works fine when I click the button in the browser, but it gives me error when I try to simulate the click with jquery.*"

Comment: The next thing to do is remove all the code that's irrelevant to the question.  It's likely a single line that's causing it, but too much effort to tell from all the code provided.  Have a read of [mcve].

Comment: Add `console.log(json)` here: `success: function(json) { console.log(json)` (don't include in question, just check it's actually what you expected and is json and not html or something else).

Answer (score 0):

try document.on click event like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', "#button-refresh", function () {
    $(this).trigger('click');
  });
});
```